# Minor Mode / Description

Tags: minor-mode, doc-strings

I'm using a minor mode for my key bindings.
But I want to set the documentation string dynamically.
Instead of:

```lisp
    (define-minor-mode mesys-mode
    "Text"
    ...)
```

I want something like this:

```lisp
    (define-minor-mode mesys-mode
    my-document-string
    ...)
```

How to do that?
I'm still a newbie to Elisp and macros in Elisp.
I experimented with `(concat "This" " and that")`, yes, it seems to expand without error but no description is shown only 'Not documented', if I use `(describe-mode "mesys-mode")`
I think there is a problem with expansion....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of constructs like `defun` and `define-minor-mode` requires that a string literal is used.

If you want to generate the doc string programmatically, you can use (at least) two methods:

- Create an data structure that corresponds to the call to `define-minor-mode`, with the resulting docstring in place. Then apply `eval` to it. Something like:

  ```
  (eval `(define-minor-mode mesys-mode ,my-document-string ...))
  ```
- Define it using a dummy docstring and set the `function-documentation` documentation of the minor mode symbol.

Unfortunately, I think it's hard to get either variant working properly with autoload:s.